# Sign in with Apple ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential returns random email when user select 'Hide My Email' option for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, apple-id, apple-sign-in

When I go through the **Sign in with apple** I am getting first time exact email address and basic details of the user which I want but second time in response there is no email field in response.

My concern is that I want email address of the user so in future I can send notification email to that particular user. but apple gives **random created email**, in reality that doesn't exists. How to contact to user in future by email?

Comment: @Javed how i get random email second time also. As i delete app & try again with Hide My Email then blank email comes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was finding solution I got to know, we have to pass an email address for following:

**The email addresses you register will be able to send and receive messages to and from customers using Apple’s private email relay service.**

[image]

Once I added this I am able to send and receive the emails.

https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/services/configure

Answer (score 1):

You might have to register the outbound email with apple, check [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplejs/communicating_using_the_private_email_relay_service) for more information on using the private email provided also look at the sign in with apple docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/sign-in-with-apple/get-started/).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the **random created email** apple gives is actually connected to user's actual mail id. All the mail you send will be forwarded to it. But they can unlink their mail in future. This gives users some privacy and protection from spamming.

Comment: I tried but every time I am getting "Email address not found"

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer :

You need to add sender email id or domain name into to your developer account.

[Add your email and domain name.](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/services/configure)

## Long answer

You need to follow below steps:

- Log in with your developer account in https://developer.apple.com
- Goto More section. Please refer below screenshot.

[image: Image 1]

- Click on configure button. Please refer below screenshot.

[image: Image2]

- Add domain and email address, You want to communicate.

[image: Image 3]

Add email and domain [here](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/services/configure)